# Numpy - float32 gives different value from dtype="float32" in array

Tags: python, numpy

Numpy Float32 value is different depending on whether initiated inside an array or as a standalone float32:

```
>>> numpy.array([75.09], dtype="float32")
array([ 75.08999634], dtype=float32)
>>> numpy.float32(75.09)
75.089996
```

I need to be able to search the array for the float32 value. Currently value is not found because of the last two extra digits. I have also tried:

```
>>> numpy.array([75.09], dtype="float32").round(decimals=6)
array([ 75.08999634], dtype=float32)
```

And:

```
>>> numpy.around(numpy.array([75.09], dtype="float32"), decimals=6)
array([ 75.08999634], dtype=float32)
```

But as you can see output still contains the last two digits.

Comment: *Results may also be **surprising** due to the inexact representation of decimal fractions in the IEEE floating point standard*

Comment: [How Futile are Mindless Assessments of Roundoff
in Floating-Point Computation ?](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Mindless.pdf)

Comment: The scalar and array versions are not different. You are just not printing the scalar value with enough precision. Mind you comparing floating points is a risky business. Use `np.isclose` or `np.allclose` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numbers are (most likely) the same, it's just a matter of how the objects are formatted as strings.

```
>>> numpy.array([75.09], dtype="float32")[0] == numpy.float32(75.09)
True
```

The problem (as you may already know) is that 75.09 seems to require a lot of precision, maybe even infinite (I didn't do the math, more about it [here](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/)).

If you want to have consistent text output just use your own string formatting.

```
>>> a = numpy.array([75.09], dtype="float32")
>>> b = numpy.float32(75.09)
>>> print 'a: [', ','.join('{:.6f}'.format(ai) for ai in a), '] b:','{:.6f}'.format(b)
a: [ 75.089996 ] b: 75.089996
>>> print 'a: [', ','.join('{:.8f}'.format(ai) for ai in a), '] b:','{:.8f}'.format(b)
a: [ 75.08999634 ] b: 75.08999634
```

Answer (score 0):

The display of the numbers is different because they are printed as a NumPy array (1) and and float (2). Try to print the first array member `numpy.array([75.09], dtype="float32")[0]`.

Comments about the finite precision of floating point numbers are also to take into account :-) Almost never will you find equality in floating point numerics.